# How do you convert a string to a variable with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to add a link to a blog_post using in this case blog.link

If for example myblog.link = new_contact_path, it would be  "new_contact_path".
In my view I am trying to create a link using 
`<%= @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <%= link_to blog.title, blog.link  %>
 <%end %>`

I tried using #{blog.link} but that does not work.
I ended up trying something else. I will post it in the answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `something_like_this = "something_like_this"`??!! Can you please demonstrate what code you are trying to write?

Comment: Ruby does not permit you to create a local variable dynamically. That could be done in v1.8 using `eval`, but not in later versions.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In particular, I don't know what you mean with "an opposite of `to_s`". `to_s` will return the string representation of an object. So, are you looking for an object representation of a `String`? But what does that even mean? Are you looking for something like `String#to_i`, which will return an integer representing the numeric content of the string?

Comment: If this is really Rails then `root_path` is a *method*, not a *variable*. This distinction makes a big different. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: As already mentioned: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for `to_sym` to build a symbol from a string?

Comment: Sorry about that everyone. What I was trying to do was (in Ruby on Rails), add a link to a post using a post.link.  I did not want to link to show in this case, I wanted to link to a path in my routes.

Comment: I edited my question and used a helper instead, I posted it in the answer.  I think Cary answered it by saying "Ruby does not permit you to create a local variable dynamically."

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert a string to a variable, for the simple reason that variables aren't objects in Ruby. If you wanted to convert a string to a variable, you would do that by either calling a method on the string, or by calling a method on some other object as passing the string as an argument. Either way, the variable would have to be returned by the method, but methods can only return objects and variables aren't objects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case I guess you should use [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-send) or [Object#public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send) methods:

```
'qwe'.send('upcase') # => "QWE"
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did instead was made a helper method.

```
def blog_action_link(link)
    case link
    when "person"
      new_person_path
    when "place"
      places_path
    else
    new_contact_path
    end
  end
```

Then I used the helper in my view instead.